# How do I connect a caller to a third party, but announce the call to the third party before connecting?

Tags: php, asterisk, agi

I'm developing a pay-per-minute call service with database integration via AGI/PHP scripting. I've got the integration part down pretty well, but I'm confused as to how to go about connecting clients with providers in a way that doesn't expose either party's personal information (e.g. CID info). Also, I must be able to track the time that the two parties are connected (for accurate billing).

Basically, here's a rundown of the call flow:

- A client requests to talk to a provider on the app
- The app generates a 6-digit access code to be used when they call the 800 number
- The client calls the hotline and enters the access code
- The server connects to database via AGI and retrieves the provider's mobile number associated with the access code
- The server calls the provider and announces that "user so-and-so is on the line." User so-and-so only hears music on hold at this point
- The provider presses a key (e.g. pound) to accept the call or another to decline
- The server announces something like "Your call is being connected, billing will begin now" to both parties
- The server connects both parties and gets out of the way, yet begins timing the call until the channel is dropped
- When the call has ended, the timer value is recorded to the database via AGI

Any ideas? I have scoured the internet for hours and have not been able to find any examples even remotely close to what I want to do.

I would appreciate any help anyone can offer, or if anyone has any examples and has done something similar to this in the past.

EDIT:

Here is my dial plan:

```
exten => 1,1,Read(acode,enter_acode,6)
same => Set(ACODE = ${acode})
same => n,agi(baba.agi,get_call,${acode})
same => n,GotoIf($["${CALLSTAT}" == "1"]?call-ok:call-bad)
same => n(call-bad),GotoIf($["${CALLSTAT}" == "2"]?ag-unavail:call-not-found)
same => n(call-not-found),Playback(acode_invalid)
same => n,Goto(baba,1,1)
same => n(ag-unavail),Read(opt,ag_unavail,1)
same => n,GotoIf($["${opt}" == "1"]?ag-notify:no-call)
same => n(ag-notify),agi(baba.agi,ag_notify,${ACODE})
same => n,GotoIf($["${NSTAT}" == "1"]?notify-ok:call-error)
same => n(notify-ok),Playback(ag_notify)
same => n,Goto(baba,s,1)
same => n(call-ok),Read(opt,call_ready,1)
same => n,GotoIf($["${opt}" == "1"]?start-call:no-call)
same => n(start-call),Playback(attempt_connect)
HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO CALL ${APHONE}
same => n,Goto(no-call)
same => n(no-call),Playback(no_call)
same => n,Goto(baba,s,1)
same => n(call-error),Playback(error_proc_req)
same => n,Goto(baba,s,1)
```

And here is the function from my PHP agi:

```
function get_call()
{
    global $db;
    log_agi("Retrieving call information for access code: {$this->agi_arg_2}");
    $q = "SELECT * FROM `call-user` WHERE `call_code`='%s' AND `call_status`=1 LIMIT 1";
    $q = sprintf($q,$this->agi_arg_2);
    $res = $db->query($q);
    db_error($db,$q);
    if ($res->num_rows > 0)
    {
        $call = $res->fetch_object();
        log_agi("Call #{$call->call_id} found! Checking agent availability...");
        if ($call->ag_avail)
        {
            log_agi("Agent is available! User Phone: {$call->user_phone}, Agent Phone: {$call->ag_phone}");
            execute_agi("SET VARIABLE CALLSTAT 1");
            execute_agi("SET VARIABLE UPHONE {$call->user_phone}");
            execute_agi("SET VARIABLE APHONE {$call->ag_phone}");
            return true;
        }else{
            log_agi("Agent [{$call->ag_username}] is unavailable!");
            execute_agi("SET VARIABLE CALLSTAT 2");
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        log_agi("Call associated with access code #{$this->agi_arg_2} was not found!");
        execute_agi("SET VARIABLE CALLSTAT 0");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I would also like to be able to do this in reserve. I.E. a client can request a callback from a provider.

Comment: SO require you share with us your code attempts or other efforts. "Any idea?" questions are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [Follow Me](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+16+Application_FollowMe) application would be of interest for you.
It has built in functionality to call the destination, play a message and have the destination to press a key to accept the call (it is 1 by default).

For billing, use the [Call Data Records (CDR)](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+16+Configuration_cdr). You can add your own fields.